# Using IFERROR with VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am adding a formula into a spreadsheet via VBA that uses iferror and vlookup.  Below is the code from the VBA

```
 LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 Range("O2:o" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1,'Controls'!a:b,2,FALSE),""Missing"")"
```

But when I look back into the spreadsheet, I find the following formula in the cells

```
  =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,Controls!A:(B),2,FALSE),"Missing")
```

which always results in a value of "Missing".  When I edited the formula in the sheet and removed the parens from the B in the lookup range, the formula resolved correctly by finding the value in the Controls sheet.

I've tried changing the lookup range from A:B to A1:B500, $A$1:$B$500, and $A:$B.  I also tried breaking it up and using various concatenations.

My question is ... How can I get VBA to NOT add the parens around the B in my lookup range.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem comes from the fact that you put a regular address (`A:B`) into a R1C1-Formula. Even if your lookup-range is in another sheet, Excel expect the address in R1C1-notation. Your formula would look like

```
dim formula as string
formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1,Controls!C[-14]:C[-13],2,FALSE),""Missing"")"
Range("O2:o" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = formula
```

as this is super ugly, I would suggest you define a name for the range `Controls!A:B`. Then you can change the formula simply to

```
formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1,MyControls,FALSE),""Missing"")"
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick and correct response.   The range worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to use `.Formula(...)` instead of `.FormulaR1C1(...)` and use uppercase on your string like `...A:B...`

Else, you could do the following:

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("O2:o" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1,'Controls'!a:b,2,FALSE),""Missing"")"
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell in Range("O2:O" & LastRow)
    cell.Formula = Replace(cell.Formula, "(B)","B")
Next cell
```

Comment: This will result in a runtime error as `Replace` will not work for a whole range. You would need a loop over all cells. And you should write the formula to property `Formula`, not `Value`.

Comment: Thanks @FunThomas, I improved the answer